# Crash when method of class is executing but smart pointer deleted the object

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I faced a problem with C++ memory management and smart pointers.
I have a code to demonstrate you the problem:

```
#include <memory>

class Closeable
{
 public:
  virtual void Close() = 0;
};

class DisconnectionHandler
{
 public:
  virtual void HandleDisconnection() = 0;
};

class EventHandler
{
 public:
  virtual void HandleEvent() = 0;
};

class Notifier
{
 public:
  virtual void OnDisconnection() = 0;
};

class RemoteSystem : public Closeable
{
 public:
  void SetReceiveDataEventHandler(const std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>& receive_data_event_handler) {
    this->receive_data_event_handler_ = receive_data_event_handler;
  }

  void Close() override { this->receive_data_event_handler_ = nullptr; }

  // In this example to simplify the code I just call this method from the main function.
  void OnDataReceived() { this->receive_data_event_handler_->HandleEvent(); }

 private:
  std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> receive_data_event_handler_;
};

class ReceiveDataEventHandler : public EventHandler
{
 public:
  explicit ReceiveDataEventHandler(const std::shared_ptr<DisconnectionHandler>& disconnection_handler)
      : disconnection_handler_(disconnection_handler) {}

  void HandleEvent() override {
    // Some code of receiving data.
    // But we can find out that connection was closed and we must call the disconnection handler.
    if (this->IsConnectionClosed()) {
      this->disconnection_handler_->HandleDisconnection();
      return;
    }
    // Some other stuff..
  }

 private:
  [[nodiscard]] bool IsConnectionClosed() const {
    // In the example code I just return true.
    return true;
  }

 private:
  const std::shared_ptr<DisconnectionHandler> disconnection_handler_;
};

class RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler : public DisconnectionHandler
{
 public:
  explicit RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler(const std::shared_ptr<Closeable>& closeable_remote_system,
                                            Notifier* notifier)
      : closeable_remote_system_(closeable_remote_system), notifier_(notifier) {}

  ~RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler() { printf("Destructed.\n"); }

  void HandleDisconnection() override {
    this->closeable_remote_system_->Close();
    printf("Closed.\n");
    this->notifier_->OnDisconnection();
    printf("Notified.\n");
  }

 private:
  const std::shared_ptr<Closeable> closeable_remote_system_;
  Notifier* const notifier_;
};

class ClientNotifier : public Notifier
{
 public:
  void OnDisconnection() override { printf("Disconnected.\n"); }
};

int main() {
  ClientNotifier notifier;

  auto remote_system = std::make_shared<RemoteSystem>();

  {
    // Scope for losing references in the main function after SetReceiveDataEventHandler.
    auto disconnection_handler = std::make_shared<RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler>(remote_system, &notifier);
    auto receive_data_event_handler = std::make_shared<ReceiveDataEventHandler>(disconnection_handler);
    remote_system->SetReceiveDataEventHandler(receive_data_event_handler);
  }

  // Only in the example.
  remote_system->OnDataReceived();

  return 0;
}
```

You can also run this code. In this example program crashes on the line `this->notifier_->OnDisconnection()`. The output of the program:

```
Destructed.
Closed.
*crash*
```

This occurs because of losing the last reference to the `ReceiveDataEventHandler` when calling method `RemoteSystem::Close` from `RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler::HandleDisconnection`, accordingly, losing the reference to the `RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler` and deleting this object. After the `Close` method and deleting both objects of classes `RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler` and `ReceiveDataEventHandler` it returns to the `RemoteSystemDisconnectionHandler::HandleDisconnection` method and prints 'Closed.' to the output, but since the object has been already deleted, the next line occurs an error, because now `this` is deleted and any access to it occurs memory exception.
I also tried to rewrite this code on Java and it works fine, unlike C++.
So, I want to ask you guys if there is a solution for this problem in the C++ community?
I thought C++ had no problems with memory management since smart pointers exist, but appearently I was wrong.
Hope for your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution I have for this problem is to add a copy of the shared_pointer to a vector somewhere, and clear that vector some time later (after the method has returned).  That way the deletion will occur sometime later, not in the middle of your method-call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to make a copy of the `shared_ptr` before invoking the method on it:

```
    void OnDataReceived()
    { 
        auto temp = this->receive_data_event_handler_;
        if (temp)
        {
            temp->HandleEvent();
        }
    }
```

`temp` will keep the pointer alive until after the method invocation has completed.

However note that if you are using multiple threads in your real code, `std::shared_ptr` is not thread safe so you need to introduce a mutex to protect access to `receive_data_event_handler_`:

```
class RemoteSystem : public Closeable
{
public:
    void SetReceiveDataEventHandler(const std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>& receive_data_event_handler) {
        this->receive_data_event_handler_ = receive_data_event_handler;
    }

    void Close() override 
    { 
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        this->receive_data_event_handler_ = nullptr;
    }

    // In this example to simplify the code I just call this method from the main function.
    void OnDataReceived()
    { 
        std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> temp;
        {
            std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
            temp = this->receive_data_event_handler_;
        }
        if (temp)
        {
            temp->HandleEvent();
        }
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> receive_data_event_handler_;
    std::mutex mutex;
};
```